# On a multisite environment, get the subdomain value as variable

Tags: multisite, dns, cloudflare

I'm trying to setup a multisite where everytime a new site is added, a DNS record is also added in Cloudflare.
So far, the code is working but I'm having troubles trying to parse the subdomain value onto a variable.

This is the code so far:

```
function create_cloudflare_dns_record() {

//$current_site = ''.$get_blog_details->siteurl.'';
//$current_site = ''.$substr( $current_site, -8).'';
//$current_site = ''.explode('.', $current_site).'';


/* Cloudflare.com | APİv4 | Api Ayarları */
$apikey     = '778***************************c37'; // Cloudflare Global API
$email      = 'al******@***********.com'; // Cloudflare Email Adress
$domain     = 'mer*****.com';  // zone_name // Cloudflare Domain Name
$zoneid     = 'ecc**********************1e1'; // zone_id // Cloudflare Domain Zone ID
//$current_site   = ''.$get_sites->path.'';
$current_site = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);


// $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

// A-record oluşturur DNS sistemi için.
$ch = curl_init("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/".$zoneid."/dns_records");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'X-Auth-Email: '.$email.'',
'X-Auth-Key: '.$apikey.'',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
// 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8',
'Content-Type:application/json',
'purge_everything: true'

));

// -d curl parametresi.
$data = array(

    'type' => 'CNAME',
    'name' => ''.$current_site.'',
    'content' => 'mer***.com',
    'zone_name' => ''.$domain.'',
    'zone_id' => ''.$zoneid.'',
    'proxied' => true,
    'ttl' => '120'
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data_string));

$sonuc = curl_exec($ch);

/*
    //print_r($sonuc);
*/

curl_close($ch);



}


add_action( 'wp_insert_site', 'create_cloudflare_dns_record' );
```

None of the three different attempts for $current_site at the beggining of the function is giving any result.

If I manually replace the value for $current_site, the code is working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_insert_site` recieves WP_Site object, which contains details about the current site.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_site/

> do_action( 'wp_insert_site', WP_Site $new_site ) Fires once a site has
> been inserted into the database.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site/

> ```
> WP_Site Object (
>     [blog_id] => 2
>     [domain] => localhost
>     [path] => /m2/sagres/
>     [site_id] => 1
>     [registered] => 2018-03-23 13:49:37
>     [last_updated] => 2019-03-05 15:52:10
>     [public] => 0
>     [archived] => 0
>     [mature] => 0
>     [spam] => 0
>     [deleted] => 0
>     [lang_id] => 0 
> )
> ```

So to summarize you can change your function definetion to accept argument.

```
function create_cloudflare_dns_record(WP_Site $new_site) {
```

And use `$new_site->domain` and `$new_site->path` to get details about the site inserted

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. It has helped me to solve the issue. Not very elegant but it does the trick. Again, thanks.
$current_site   = ''.$new_site->domain.'';
$pieces = explode(".", $current_site);
$sub-domain = $pieces[0];

Comment: @AlvaroGilabert if my answer helped you can you please mark my answer as accepted and upvote it please ?

Comment: I already did but this message appeared: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.